# Magento multishipping : get all orders or orderIds

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get all "order" in a multishipping order in the confirmation page.

In standard mode i use :

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
```

or

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```

But when i use that in multishipping mode, i always get an old order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have `multishipping order` you still will have one quote, but few orders linked to this quote.
 1. Get last quote id:

```
$lastQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId();
```

2. Get orders for this quote:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', array('eq' => $lastQuoteId));
$orders = $orderCollection->getItems();
```

or order ids:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
$orderCollection->getSelect()
     ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
     ->columns('entity_id');
```